# Angular 2 - Error during instantiation of Router - (Router Outlet ->Router)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

**EDIT**
Here is my plunker: [plnkr.co/edit/qMBc5j62jQoBJLsFYgr4?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/qMBc5j62jQoBJLsFYgr4?p=preview))

I'm using TypeScript.

I'm getting the following error:

> Error during instantiation of Router! (RouterLink -> Router).
>   and (RouterOutlet -> Router)

I have tried the different solutions on this forum for this problem, including adding/changing `<base href="/">` in `index.html` or adding  `APP_BASE_HREF` to bootstrap.

I have been using the code off the official Angular Plunker tutorial http://plnkr.co/edit/d8pewJf9kVqD3kTSvQmK?p=preview, which works fine.

My app.component.ts looks as follows:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {LandingComponent} from './landing.component';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 template: `
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['Landing']">Heroes</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
 directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
 providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@RouteConfig({
 {
    path: '/landing',
    name: 'Landing',
    component: LandingComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
}

 })

export class AppComponent { 
 title = 'Win Free!';
}
```

main.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

index.html

```
<html>
 <head>

 <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');  </script>
      <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
      <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.12/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.8.9/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/router.dev.js"></script>


    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: almost evey thing seems alright. Do you have your code plunker?

Comment: your plnkr works fine, where is error in your plnkr ?

Comment: @PardeepJain. That is not his plunker. He is using it for his reference.

Comment: opps i think this one his plnkr area ;)

Comment: Yes, the plunker I previously linked is the official Angular 2 plunker. This is my plunker [link] (https://plnkr.co/edit/qMBc5j62jQoBJLsFYgr4?p=preview) 

I should also note that '{{title}}' bindings in 'app.component.ts' stop working when the routing is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` from `AppComponent`. `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should be shared by the whole application by only adding it to `boostrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS])`.

If you add them on the components `providers` as well, then the component gets a new instance, which prevents them from working as intended.

**Update**

In your Plunker (the linke after `Edit ...`) has `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` only on the component, but not in `bootstrap()` but it should be the other way around. There was also a syntax problem in `@RouteConfig()` which expects an array but was `{}` (instead of `[]`).

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uzuK9zizIF8dsLmtdBoN?p=preview)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Odd, as I'm using the same structure as the official angular plunker I linked above.

Comment: It works now. I updated the `@RouteConfig` to use an `[]` and the `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` as well. Thank you.